# Nested selects in LINQ expression, how to?

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I don't know how to work with nested selects in LINQ.
How could I convert this SQl expression to LINQ?

```
Select i.ID, i.Impression, 
(Select COUNT(ImpressionsId) 
    from DiaryImpressions 
    where DiaryPostsId = '2' AND ImpressionsId = i.ID) as Num from Impressions i
```

Comment: things such as this made me look for better solutions.  Joining in linq just makes you cry... You may consider looking at this simple but wonderful tool (dapper) http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: I believe this can also be rewritten as a JOIN, with an equivalent RA model. The plans might be a little different though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from ...
select new { 
    i.Id, 
    i.Impression, 
    Count = context.DiaryImpressions.Count(d => d.DiaryPostsId == 2 && d.ImpressionsId == i.Id)
 }
```

If you map your objects properly, you can use child relations directly:

```
Count = i.DiaryImpressions.Count(d => d.DiaryPostsId == 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seriously? DiaryPostsId is a string? Oh well...

```
from i in context.Impressions
select new {
    i.ID,
    i.Impressions,
    Num = (from d in context.DiaryImpressions
           where d.DiaryPostsId == "2"
           && d.ImpressionsId == i.ID
           select d).Count()
}
```